# OnClick on Button

Tags: button, onclick, console.log

Okay, I would like to put an onClick event on a button. For some reason this code doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<button id="who" class="hidden">Arresteer een verdachte!</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var button = document.getElementById("who");

    button.onclick(function(){
        console.log("hoi")
        })
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

your button id is who no button :

```
document.getElementById("who");
```

Update:

```
  document.getElementById("who").onclick = function () { alert('hello!'); };
```

OR

```
var el = document.getElementById("who");
if (el.addEventListener)
    el.addEventListener("click", doFunction, false);
else if (el.attachEvent)
    el.attachEvent('onclick', doFunction);
```

Comment: I changed that, Thanks! It still doesn't work though. There's an error with the function. It says: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "onclick" function and assign click event, like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("hoi");
});
```